# What does 'static' mean in this Java code?

Tags: java

I have basic knowledge of Java and fair amount of experience working with other OOP languages, but this code still looks very strange to me. Can you help?

```
public abstract class Hello
{
    protected static Name name;
    static { /** what does this mean? **/
        name = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a static initialization block, in which you initialize static class members.